# How to send a list as multipart/form-data in Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm surprised by how hard this has been for such a trivial thing, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I want to write a `requests.post` function call that basically recreates this `curl`:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \ 
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F to=alice@example.com \
    -F to=bob@example.com \
```

Ignoring the auth portion, I tried this

```
requests.post(url, files={"to":["alice@example.com", "bob@example.com"]})
```

However using `curlify` you can see that only `bob@example.com` is passed to the request (and the API behavior mirrors this fact).

A deeper look into the library source code for `requests` shows why this happens (see `_encode_files` in  https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/models.py) but I still can't figure out how to get it to do what I want.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `requests.post(url, data={"to":["alice@example.com", "bob@example.com"]})` work for you?

Comment: It does on this API however, would this send in multipart form data encoding?

Comment: I don't think it's possible through the interface. Check out the [requests toolbelt](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt), which can help, but you still have to create the request yourself.